# Unable to locate credentials setting up airflow connection through env variables

Tags: python, amazon-s3, airflow, hook, credentials

So I am trying to set up an S3Hook in my airflow dag, by setting the connection programmatically in my script, like so

```
from airflow.hooks.S3_hook import S3Hook
from airflow.models import Connection
from airflow import settings

def s3_test_hook():

    conn = Connection(
        conn_id='aws-s3',
        conn_type='s3',
        extra={"aws_access_key_id":aws_key, 
                "aws_secret_access_key": aws_secret},
        )
```

I can run the `conn` line no problem, which tells me the connection can be made. `aws_key` and `aws_secret` are loaded int through dotenv with an .env file I have in my local directory.

However when I run the next two lines in the function:

```
    s3_hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id='aws-s3')
    find_bucket = s3_hook.check_for_bucket('nba-data')
```

to check for a bucket I know exists.. I receive this error

```
NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you have created an Airflow `Connection` object, but this doesn't do anything by itself. When a hook is given a connection id, it will look up the given id in various locations (in this order):

- Secrets backend (if configured)
- Environment variable `AIRFLOW_CONN_*`
- Airflow metastore

Your connection is currently only defined in code, but Airflow is unable to locate it in any of the three locations above.

The Airflow documentation provides some pointers for configuring an AWS connection: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/connections/aws.html

Comment: Where does Airflow read the Environment Variable, `AIRFLOW_CONN_AWS_S3` from? It's in my dockerfile.dev, so running my dag on my local airflow server will execute. But If i'm running code line by line in spyder, the script is not in that docker environment, so I'm not sure where to set that conn id